# Button Listenner not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with 3 input button and I want to add listenner on these buttons; but only submit and reset are working, not button. I don't understand what's wrong

Html side

```
<form id="form_infos">
    <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="btn btn-success" />
    <input type="button" value="Copier" class="btn btn-success" />
    <input type="reset" value="Supprimer" class="btn btn-danger" />
</form>
```

Js side

```
var form_infos = document.getElementById('form_infos');
form_infos.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

form_infos.addEventListener('button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

form_infos.addEventListener('reset', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Button is not an event as you are specifying in the function

Comment: [`button` is not a valid Form event.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Comment: But then what am I supposed to do ? If there is only 2 buttons event and I need a third button ? I should use reset or submit and find a way to detect which button is clicked there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax of `addEventListener`:

> document.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture)

As you can see, the first parameter is the event and the button that you are specifying is not an event.

Comment: But then what am I supposed to do ? If there is only 2 buttons event and I need a third button ? I should use reset or submit and find a way to detect which button is clicked there ?

Comment: You want to identify what functionality you want that button to perform and then identify during which event that functionality should be performed. Now pointing to that button and specifying the required event, you can write the addEventListener method.

Comment: I have 3 functionality and each one of them should be activated when the button is clicked, it's as simple as that. But I see there is only two events for buttons...

Comment: If you have three functionality, then you better refer to each input fields and add a click EventListener for the same.

Comment: Okay then I will do that, sad we can't extends events but I guess it makes sense because events has to be understood by each navigators. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help..upvote would be preferred if you understood what I said :D

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because I have less than 15 points or some stupid things like that :(

Comment: Damn these privileges :(

Answer (score -1):

Because `submit` and `reset` are the events. `button` is not event.

Please refer the **HTML DOM Events**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp